# Intercom how to include app into conversation by using api

Tags: intercom

I want to add special app into intercom conversation as below image.

[intercom conversation with app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbJX7.png)

Of course, I can pick one app in app list manually and include it to conversation, but what I want is to do it automatically by using python-intercom.

I searched all edges of python-intercom, but couldn't find any clue.

Would you please tell me how to implement it?

That's okay even if it's not python script, and I hope to know if it's enable.

Hope to get your help.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't insert an app via the API.

However, via the API, you can grab the user's response to your question and assign/manipulate this value as needed. In this example, you can fetch the user's response and assign the name value to them using the `users` API.

That said, it sounds like you should consider Intercom's Operator features. I.e. in your example above, it seems that you're describing the exact use case for either a Custom Bot or Task Bot. I don't fully understand your use case, but based on what I'm seeing, it seems like a *don't reinvent the wheel* situation. [For more information on how Intercom's Operator works see here.](https://www.intercom.com/help/operator/how-can-i-access-task-bots-and-custom-bots) If I'm off, please feel free to share more about your use case. Thanks and best of luck~